# import styles not working in a basic JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

We are upgrading a project from React 16 to React 18.2 (it is a difficult challenge).

One JavaScript file that was working before is not working now.

The file contains a simple import:

```
import styles from './toolbar.css';
```

toolbar.css contains basic styling:

```
div.toolbar-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}
```

and some other stuff.

These styles are applied in the toolbar.js file:

```
 $('body').append(
                '<div class="toolbar-container"><ul class="menubuttons" style="display: none;">' +

console.log(Object.keys(styles));  //shows "length: 0"
```

So for some reason a simple import that was working is no longer working.

Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: Guess you cannot import a css file like js module.

Comment: Is this javascript or react specific?

Comment: Rename the file as `toolbar.module.css`, then importing it (`import styles from './toolbar.module.css';`) should work.

Comment: @Unmitigated why is that? https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules seems to show something different?

Comment: CSS ain't no JS module. JS has no clue how to import this. It's your bundler that makes this import work. So if this no longer works, take a look at your build pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import stylings as below

`import './toolbar.css';`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import CSS files in javascript.

`import` retrieves the `export` from the js/ts file you request.
CSS is a stylesheet and doesn't contain readable code for javascript.

I do not know much about react, but you can create a `<style>` element to the values of the CSS file, or create a `<link href="">` element to your .css file.